# Best way to pass a date parameter in a Restful way?

Tags: rest, date, restful-architecture

I'm building an Restful API that, in some case, accepts a Date as parameter for the listing.

For example, I have the url /api/members/ and we can filter with the `created` date parameter.

Now, I'd like to accept that date in many ways :

- Before (or equal) to that given date
- After (or equal) to that given date
- Equal to that given date
- Between two given date

Here's the solution I came up with, I'm wondering if this is appropriate or if there is a better alternative :

The parameter created will accept date as string (Iso 8601 standard, YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) values. This parameter can be prepended with these values :

> , <, <=, >=, = (default, if not mentionned).

By doing so, the user can request the list of members where created is before a certain date by doing :

```
?created=%3C2014-02-19 # (<)
?created=%3C%3D2014-02-19 15:00:00 # (<=)
?created=%3E2014-02-19 14:00:00 # (>)
?created=%3E%3D2014-02-18 # (>=)
?created=%3D2014-02-19 # =
?created=2014-02-19 # This is EXACTLY the same as the previous one.
```

Using a JSON representation of the query (what you'd pass as `data` in your jQuery.ajax) :

```
{'created': '<2014-02-19'}
{'created': '<=2014-02-19 15:00:00'}
{'created': '>2014-02-19 14:00:00'}
{'created': '>=2014-02-18'}
{'created': '=2014-02-19'}
{'created': '2014-02-19'} # This is EXACTLY the same as the previous one.
```

For the "between" two date, created can also accept two values, in that case, no prepended suffix will be accepted, something like :

```
?created[]=2014-02-01&created[]=2014-02-28
```

Again, as a jQuery.ajax parameter :

```
{'created': [2014-02-01, 2014-02-28]}
```

What do you think of this implementation ?

Comment: If these are query parameters (I was initially confused because they look like JSON payloads), then I'm not sure whether I'd make the query parameters look like JSON (maybe I'd remove quotes around created, spaces, and curly braces: created:>=2014-02-18 ). I do like the operators as a readable, concise way of specifying the ranges.

Comment: You are right, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: is there an option for multiple ranges? i.e: `date1 OR date2'

Comment: Not as it comes, but you can request multiple times with created=n